# Magento 2: Add product attribute to product by SQL

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute

I am trying to add a product attribute to a product in Magento 2 by SQL, but its there is some issue in it.

```
product id is = 244992
product attribute code is = 70
```

Comment: Do you want to add attribute to a product?? Also, please share the error information if you've any.

Comment: Yes assign attribute to product

Comment: Please give a try with my answer.